# jQuery SPA Dynamically created elements, trigger events multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, eventtrigger

I made some 'SPA interface' using jquery, my main function which load pages, looks like that:

```
$('body').on('click', '.go-to', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var main_container = $('#main-container');
    main_container.fadeOut('fast');
    $('.preloader').delay(400).fadeIn('slow');
    $.get(_this.attr('href'), { id : _this.attr('data-id') }, function(result) {
        main_container.html(result);
        $('.preloader').fadeOut('fast');
        main_container.delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
    });
    return false;
});
```

When I load some page multiple times, the event for loaded element is triggered many times.
For example when i load page1 5 times, this code will return 'Test' 5 times.

```
   $('body').on('click', '#select-all', function(event) {
      console.log('Test');
   });
```

Anybody knows how to fix it?

Comment: Are you loading the script multiple times?

Comment: Yes, i'm. This is the reason of my issue. Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use safely `.off()` before loading the `.on()` again to remove the previous `.on()` event handler you issued from the same js script you loaded

```
$('body').off('click');
$('body').on('click', '#select-all', function(event) {
      console.log('Test');
   });
```

http://api.jquery.com/off/

but as a practice why do you need to load again the event listener? **I recommend you to just only load the event listener once as `.on()` binds event to any dynamically generated element**

Comment: I think it will be better to find the cause of the issue and fix it rather than fixing the wrong code by some means.

Comment: its not really a wrong code, I just give him an advice to solve his current situation, I encountered this before as my event listener's codes are loaded from ajax so it means the event listeners will be loaded as I received them from ajax responses.

Comment: You don't understand what is the problem. I don't to trigger event only once. The reason of my issue is loading .js file multiple time. So the function on() is execute multiple times.

Comment: @KamilMichalski that's why i am telling you to use `.off()` so that even your js that contains `.on()` is loaded many times, the previous loaded `.on()` code will be removed by `.off()` thus solving your problem

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks a lot. But i think, no load .on() many times is better solutuon. Anyway thanks!